# GetSchema( "Views") - how to exlude sys owner items to speed up execution?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, performance

I use the following code for Views retreivement

```
restrictionsArray = new string[ 2 ];
schema = connection.GetSchema( "Views", restrictionsArray );
```

It takes around 240 seconds and returns a table 7500 rows, 25 columns. I use .Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle. Most of the items belong to 'sys' owner.

Other code

```
restrictionsArray = new string[ 2 ];
schema = connection.GetSchema( "Tables", restrictionsArray );
```

Gives around 30 Rows and works instantly.

Is there a way to omit 'sys' owned items?

Comment: 7500 objects is a lot, have you looked at the results it returns and determine whether it is the data you want, not anything else? Does it return just view names, or the view text as well?

Comment: Yes, it is a lot. It is the default Oracle installation with an example database provided by the installer. There are 25 columns in returned data, I just need view names (VIEW_NAME column).

Comment: It sounds like you are pulling SYS views (it has around 7K in 19c). Make sure your API is called in such a way to definitely limit it to a specific schema and exclude SYS.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude sys by left everything else ?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and ask specifically how to do this. Someone with experience with calling this particular .NET API would need to help you.

Comment: _" .Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle."_ - you mean you're using the `System.Data.OracleClient` library? if so, what version? Are you aware that it's been deprecated for years now? ...you should be using [ODP.NET](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/dotnet/odp.html) instead.  Also, [have you tried just querying `ALL_VIEWS` directly](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/refrn/ALL_VIEWS.html#GUID-0FE29B36-0882-47AE-A54E-A01FC9C4100A)?

Answer (score 2):

`DbConnection.GetSchema` is an ADO.NET API that is not guaranteed to be *performantly* implemented by ADO.NET providers (even so, 240 seconds for a metadata query is excessive - I'm guessing you're on a high-latency connection and ADO.NET is doing an *RBAR query*, which might explain it).

An alternative approach is to [just query Oracle's metadata views directly](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/refrn/ALL_VIEWS.html#GUID-0FE29B36-0882-47AE-A54E-A01FC9C4100A) (their `ALL_VIEWS` view is roughly equivalent to the ISO SQL `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` metadata view):

Like so:

```
using( OracleConnection c = ... )
using( OracleCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand() )
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT v.VIEW_NAME FROM ALL_VIEWS AS v WHERE v.OWNER <> 'sys'";

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    using( OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
    {
        while( rdr.Read() )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( rdr.GetString( 0 ) );
        }
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine( "Took {0:N0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds );
}
```